# JavaScript code to schedule a content

Tags: javascript

I want to schedule a content for a specific date in my website, this code works but it only displays the content in months 10, 11 & 12 the rest months 1-9 it doesn't..i want to to display for every month...  plzz help me with it

```
function autogoLive() {

    var goLiveMonth = "10" // Month you want your content to start displaying. Two digits.
    var goLiveDay = "20" // Day you want your content to start displaying. Two digits.
    var goLiveYear = "2015" // Year you want your content to start displaying. Four digits.

    /* This is where you put your content. Make sure you escape any quotation marks with a backslash. Make sure you do not delete the opening and closing quotes. */

    var myContent = "This text will display, <strong>beginning and ending</strong> on the dates you have set."

    /* Don't edit below this line. Don */

    var goLiveDate = goLiveYear + goLiveMonth + goLiveDay; // puts START year, month, and day together.

    var nowDate = new Date();
    var day = nowDate.getUTCDate();
    var month = nowDate.getUTCMonth();
    var correctedMonth = month + 1; //month - JavaScript starts at "0" for January, so we add "1"

    if (correctedMonth < 10) { /* if less than "10", put a "0" in front of the number. */
        correctedMonth = "0" + correctedMonth;
    }

    if (day < 10) { /* if less than "10", put a "0" in front of the number. */
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    var year = nowDate.getYear(); /* Get the year. Firefox and Netscape might use century bit, and two-digit year. */

    if (year < 1900) {
        year = year + 1900; /*This is to make sure Netscape AND FireFox doesn't show the year as "107" for "2007." */
    }

    var GMTdate = year + "" + correctedMonth + "" + day; //corrected month GMT date.

    if ((GMTdate >= goLiveDate)) {
        document.write(myContent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: [`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) has been deprecated in favor of [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), which will already give you `2015` instead of `115`.

Comment: "*i want to to display for every month*" Can you please explain this further? Are you wanting to remove the date as a condition? Or, display the content for certain days within each month?

Answer (score 0):

I would compare date objects rather then string objects so something like this

```
Var showDate=new Date("January 1, 2016"); // date you want the content to appear 
Var today =new Date();
if(today>=showDate){
     //function to show your content
}
```

More information on how to use date objects can be found [on the Mozilla JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

The problem with your above code is it is comparing strings, not numbers or dates, so they don't always appear as greater than or less than in the way you'd expect.

I've attached some functioning code it does use jquery but im sure you could use the general form regardless.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var showDate= new Date('November 22, 2015 16:05:00');
var today= new Date();
if(today>=showDate){
$('div').append('<p>Hello World</p>');
}
});
```

```html
<div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This code is not working.Can you please help me with it?